# Can I change the read/write permissions for a notebook/section/page using the OneNote API?

Tags: onenote

The POST and GET actions on `/notebooks` have a `userRole` property that indicates if the user can perform read/write operations on a Notebook. I'd like to change this programmatically to allow things like sharing notebooks with other users. I've looked through the documentation but haven't found anything that lets me change the `userRole` for a notebook, section or page.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no API to do that right now. If you would like to suggest that this be added, please go to the OneNote API Uservoice site to vote: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis